# Send HaProxy log data to Graylog

Tags: logging, haproxy, graylog

how can I send "haproxy" log data to my "graylog" server ?
can I do so using "netcat" ?

I need to log all requests and responses ( with request body and response body ),
to graylog.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Per Graylog docs it can use syslog as an input -> http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/sending_data.html#syslog

haproxy can output logs to syslog -> https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#3.1-log

Here is an example of the haproxy config `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`:

```
global
  log /dev/log len 65535 local0
  ...
```

Here is an example of the rsyslog config `/etc/rsyslog.d/22-haproxy.conf`:

```
$FileCreateMode 0644
$MaxMessageSize 66k
$template haproxy,"%rawmsg%\n"
local0.* -<path_to_your_haproxy_log_file>;haproxy
& stop
```